# Storing files locally and sending jobs to printer for speed

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, raspberry-pi

I'm operating in a factory setting where speed is important. I store order information in the cloud. Barcodes are printed by querying the database for information. Operators use a tkinter app on a raspberry pi that runs a python script to query the cloud.

Currently printing out a barcode takes about 5 seconds to make that query and then use `os.system()` to print out the barcode.

1. Is there a faster way to send jobs to the printer?
2. I've been looking into storing files locally to speed this process up, does anyone have any of what to look into? Network attached storage that downloads relevant files from the cloud nightly?
3. Any suggestions for running modern factory automation with python?

Answer (score 0):

checkout [subprocess.Popen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system), which is a flexible/lite version of os.system()

Comment: I have not seen any speed improvements with `subprocess`